# Web application with QR code reader

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app, reader

Hi I want to build an library automation but I want use QR code for books.
And I want to read QR code from mobile and could I do that from web application to read qr code from mobile and conver to form data after I can save information books. Is it possible . Or should I do hybrid-mobile-application later read QR code as mobile client .And which tech are opensource and fast like ZXing.If possible could I do all of them with javascript

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can read a QR code from a web application. There are javascript libraries that enable you to scan a QR code using a camera from a mobile phone. Here is one: https://github.com/jbialobr/JsQRScanner. This is a port of ZXing QRReader to javascript. Note that many browsers only allows you to use a webcam when your website is served via http**s**.

Comment: But it don't work even I open web browser in pc / mobile ,

Comment: Please, create an issue on the project git hub page, where you can provide detailed data about your OS, web browser and a screenshot of what you see. https://github.com/jbialobr/JsQRScanner/issues

Comment: Thank you ,I wouldn't know that